# How to filter php associative array by key and values?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Hair Transplantation
            [price] => € 1000 - 4000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Rhinoplasty
            [price] => € 2500
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Otoplasty
            [price] => € 1000
        )

)
```

I want to filter this array by `price` key and, as a result, I want to be returned only one item, item with lowest price number.

Thank you!

Comment: I guess the first item has a range of prices? How should that sort compared to items with single prices?

Comment: The price here is a string and not an integer. Any reason why you have it so?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, hi, thank you for your response.
Yes. The first item (in this case) have range, get the lowest item from that range and filter that number with other single prices.

Comment: @vivek_23, yes that is a string with "€" sign, I want to remove that sign and return the only number who will be filtered.

Comment: This can be done, but it will require some unreliable string parsing--especially around the ranges. You should really look at fixing this data structure

Comment: Loop -> preg_match to get first number -> calculate minimum.

Comment: Thanks, guys, I'll do something.

Comment: if the data is fetched from the database, why not to fetch the needed item at once?

Comment: If `Hair Transplantation` is € 1000 - 4000 and therefore € 1000 then it is equal to `Otoplasty`, so which one do you want?

Comment: Seriously storing separate `price_min` and `price_max` values, with the first being the fixed price if no range is given. Store integers only -- and generate strings on the fly for your UI as necessary. Will save you from bugs down the road. Remember: you need to parse the price strings here now, but there's a good chance you'll also need integer values elsewhere in the future. In which case you will be parsing them again, and again, so rather just don't, and change the datatype/structure instead.)

Answer (score 4):

```
$data = [/* your data */];
uasort($data, function($a, $b) {
    preg_match("/\d+/", $a['price'], $matchesA);
    preg_match("/\d+/", $b['price'], $matchesB);
    return (int)$matchesB[0] <=> (int)$matchesA[0];
});

$result = array_pop($data);
```

Added (08.08.2020)
Because of vivek_23's comment, I added second solution:

```
    $result = array_reduce($price, 'getMinimumPrice', null);

    function getMinimumPrice(?array $itemA, array $itemB): array
    {
        if (is_null($itemA)) {
            return $itemB;
        }
        return getPrice($itemA) < getPrice($itemB)
            ? $itemA
            : $itemB;
    }
    
    function getPrice(array $item): int
    {
        preg_match("/\d+/", $item['price'], $matches);
        return $matches[0];
    }
```

And also I check the speed difference:

```
$primary = [
    [
        'name' => 'Hair Transplantation',
        'price' => '€ 1000 - 4000',
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Rhinoplasty',
        'price' => '€ 2500',
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Otoplasty',
        'price' => '€ 1000',
    ],
    /* ... 155 items */
];

function getMinimumPrice(?array $itemA, array $itemB): array
{
    if (is_null($itemA)) {
        return $itemB;
    }
    return getPrice($itemA) < getPrice($itemB)
        ? $itemA
        : $itemB;
}

function getPrice(array $item): int
{
    preg_match("/\d+/", $item['price'], $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}

$timeRepeat = 1000;
$reduce = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $timeRepeat; $i++) {
    $start = microtime(true);
    $price = $primary;
    array_reduce($price, 'getMinimumPrice', null);
    $reduce += microtime(true) - $start;
}

$uasort = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $timeRepeat; $i++) {
    $start = microtime(true);
    $price = $primary;
    uasort($price, function($a, $b) {
        preg_match("/\d+/", $a['price'], $matchesA);
        preg_match("/\d+/", $b['price'], $matchesB);
        return (int)$matchesB[0] <=> (int)$matchesA[0];
    });
    array_pop($price);
    $uasort += microtime(true) - $start;
}

print_r([
    'uasort' => $uasort,
    'reduce' => $reduce,
    'difference' => round($uasort / $reduce, 12),
]);
```

My results:

```
Array (
       [uasort] => 8.0096476078033
       [reduce] => 2.1610336303711
       [difference] => 3.706396557294
)
```

Comment: Clever and short. It does assume that if there's a range given, the lowest is written first (left to right). I think it's a safe assumption, though. Nice work!

Comment: ( plus 1 from me) :)

Comment: Could replace all lines in `uasort` with `return (int)trim($a['price'], "€") <=> (int)trim($b['price'], "€");`

Comment: I don't support sorting if all you need is just the min. Sorting is too expensive.

Comment: @vivek_23, I bet that it is nothing compare with input/output cost. Your worries are like getting couple Big Macs and Coke Zero : )

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

`$items` is your base array.

```
$items = [
    0 => [
        "name" => "Hair Transplantation",
        "price" => "€ 1000 - 4000"
    ],

    1 => [
        "name" => "Rhinoplasty",
        "price" => "€ 2500"
    ],
    2 => [
        "name" => "Otoplasty",
        "price" => "€ 1000"
    ]
];

$lowestPrice = PHP_INT_MAX;
$rightKey = -1;

foreach ( $items as $key => $item )
{
    $clean = str_replace('€ ', '', $item['price']);
    $chunks = explode('-', $clean);

    if ( count($chunks) == 2 )
        $price = floatval(trim($chunks[0]));
    else
        $price = floatval(trim($clean));

    if ( $price < $lowestPrice )
    {
        $lowestPrice = $price;
        $rightKey = $key;
    }
}

$lowestItem = $items[$rightKey];

print_r($lowestItem);
```

EDIT: Regex version

```
$items = [
    0 => [
        "name" => "Hair Transplantation",
        "price" => "€ 1000 - 4000"
    ],

    1 => [
        "name" => "Rhinoplasty",
        "price" => "€ 2500"
    ],
    2 => [
        "name" => "Otoplasty",
        "price" => "€ 1000"
    ]
];

$lowestPrice = PHP_INT_MAX;
$rightKey = -1;

foreach ( $items as $key => $item )
{
    $matches = [];

    if ( !preg_match('#([0-9\.]+) #', str_replace(',', '.', $item['price']), $matches) )
        continue;

    $price = floatval($matches[0]);

    if ( $price < $lowestPrice )
    {
        $lowestPrice = $price;
        $rightKey = $key;
    }
}

$lowestItem = $items[$rightKey];

print_r($lowestItem);
```

Comment: This gets it done, but it's a little spread out and "knows too much" about the format of the `price` string. Given how unideal string parsing is, the less the code needs to know about the format, the better. (Admittedly, the regexes in my answer will blow up if decimals or commas appear in the numbers, but we could pre-plan for that). Good work, though! +1

Comment: I made some fixes, write down in one shot ... But If you are unsure, clearly, replace the research by a regex that get the first full number appearing in item['line']

Comment: Here it is with a regex

Comment: I removed 999999 for PHP_INT_MAX, more explicit about the intent.

Comment: ... and improved the way of taking care of comma or point value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the data structure, as I noted in the comments on the question. It leads to string parsing which is not ideal.

I accomplished it, however, using

- [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)
- [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)
- [`min`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php)

The following code will produce your desired result in the variable, `$lowest_item`. If any of them have the same price (or same starting price), the first one that was defined will be the one returned (it could be edited to adjust which gets preference, though).

```
<?php

$data = [
    [
        'name' => 'Hair Transplantation',
        'price' => '€ 1000 - 4000',
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Rhinoplasty',
        'price' => '€ 2500',
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Otoplasty',
        'price' => '€ 1000',
    ],
];


$lowest_item = array_reduce($data, function ($carry, $item) {
    $return_to_next = null;

    if (!$carry) {
        $return_to_next = $item;
    } else if ($carry['price'] === $item['price']) {
        $return_to_next = $carry;
    } else {
        preg_match_all('/\d+/', $carry['price'], $carry_prices, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
        preg_match_all('/\d+/', $item['price'], $item_prices, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

        $carry_compare = min($carry_prices[0]);
        $item_compare = min($item_prices[0]);

        if ($carry_compare <= $item_compare) {
            $return_to_next = $carry;
        } else {
            $return_to_next = $item;
        }
    }

    return $return_to_next;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$people = array(
    0 => array(
      'name' => 'Hair Transplantation',
      'price' => '€ 1000 - 4000'
    ),
    1=> array(
      'name' => 'Rhinoplasty',
      'price' => '€ 2500'
    ),
    2=> array(
        'name' => 'Otoplasty',
        'price' => '€ 1000'
    )
);

$price = array_map(function($value) {
    if (strpos($value, '-') !== false) {
        $value = explode("-", $value)[0];
    }
    list($symbol, $price) = sscanf($value,'%[^0-9]%s');
    return intval($price);
}, array_column($people, 'price'));

$found_key = array_search(min($price),$price);

print_r($people[$found_key]) ;
```